# Cannot call method  of undefined

Tags: javascript

Такой код выдает ошибку "Cannot call method of undefined" что делать?)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: path_shell,
    cache:false,
    data: {
        flag_iq: 2,
        id_quest: iq_id[Tests.iq_question_number],
        masslenght: iq_id.length,
        number: Tests.iq_question_number
    },
    success: setTimeout(function(data){
        $('#preloader').hide();

        var arr = data.split(['!##!'],[4]);

        $('#numer').html(arr[1]);
        $('#main_iq').html(arr[2]) ;

        if (iq_id[Tests.iq_question_number] in Tests.iq_answer) {
            var a=Tests.iq_answer[iq_id[Tests.iq_question_number]];
            console.log(a);
            $('body').find('#'+a).addClass('checked');

        },1000)
```

Comment: @Михаил2342, посмотреть в отладчике какая строка вызывает ошибку и написать сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас код бредовый, вы в success передаете не функцию, а результат выполнения setTimeout, т.е. его id и когда он отрабатывает, то закономерно падает с ошибкой на строке `var arr = data.split(['!##!'],[4]);` т.к. `date` в этом случае будет `undefined`.